# No recibo el dato enviado desde javascript (fetch) a php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Intento hacer un mini proyecto para practicar el uso del fetch(), la idea es hacer un buscador el cual consiste en digitar un dato en un input, al estar tecleando irá mostrando informacion que contenga parte de ese dato digitado. La cosa es que tengo un error, no le está llegando el dato a el php.
y manda este error:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.
Si en el php le doy un valor a la variable "$search" funciona a la perfeciòn mandando los resultados pero por supuesto no estaría haciendo nada....
la verdad no se mucho de php, quisiera saber que puedo hacer para que reciba el dato.
tambien me gustaria su opinion si estoy haciendo buenas prácticas en php y javascript.

JS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function 
 PrimeraFuncion() {
console.log("Hola desde el inicio del js")

const search = document.getElementById(`text`)
const card = document.getElementById("card")

search.addEventListener(`keyup`, e => {
    if(search.value){
        console.log(search.value)

            let searchword2 = search.value 
            let template = ``

        fetch(`consult.php`,{
            method: 'POST',
            body: searchword2
        })
        .then( response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            console.log(data[0].NAME)
            template += `
            <li>
                ${data[0]}
            </li>
            `
            card.innerHTML = template
        })
        console.log(typeof(searchword2))
    }
})
})
```

PHP

```
 <?php
 include_once("db.php");

$search = $_POST['search'];
if(!empty($search)){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM task WHERE NAME LIKE '$search%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $json = [];
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $json[] = array(
            'ID' => $row['ID'],
            'NAME' => $row['NAME'],
            'DESCRIPTION' => $row['DESCRIPTION']
        );
    }
    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;
}?>
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="text" name="txt">
    <button type="submit" id="btn" >BUSCAR</button>

<div id="card">
    <!-- acà llegara la informaciòn -->
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nosé mucho de PHP, pero podrías decir en qué línea te muestra el error, ( de acuerdo al mensaje es solo error de sintaxis) y así poder ayudarte

Comment: No estas verificando que efectivamente llegue algo en $post a php. Usa is_set para verificarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que veo es que no estás mandando los datos correctamente.

Intenta reemplazando:

```
let searchword2 = search.value 
let template = ``

fetch(`consult.php`,{
    method: 'POST',
    body: searchword2
})
```

Por:

```
let searchword2 = search.value 
let template = ``
let body = new FormData();
body.append('search', searchword2);

fetch(`consult.php`,{
    method: 'POST',
    body: body
})
```

Comment: Te recomendaría cambiar esas comillas que has colocado ya que podría generar problemas si copian y pegan este código.